# Birch reduction- 1,4-cyclohexadiene over 1,3-cyclohexadiene

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]
While reading of birch reduction I was confused as of why  1,4-cyclohexadiene is prefered over 1,3-cyclohexadiene,  the latter which ought to have been the major product due to conjugation.
One of the reason I felt could be of this outcome was "symmetry".
The symmetry produced by the product could cancel the dipole forces acting on the cis- bonds, making the molecule stable. But is this sole reason sufficient to overpower the conjugation? Please explain. 
Edit: another possible reason I feel could be is the stereochemistry of the product. The product could facilitate more efficient structure in space about it's double bond (again symmetry), where as 1,3-cyclohexadiene formation could face issues of rotational barriers and might increase torsional strain on it.

Comment: Symmetry does not inherently lead to any stability. The product is not thermodynamically favoured, but is kinetically favoured: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_reduction#Reaction_regioselectivity see the last paragraph in this section.

Comment: Orthocresol thank you. I got it. So as it is kinetically favoured, the reaction was too quick to occur. Instead of stabilising it spontaneously formed the kinetically favoured product, 1,4-cyclohexadiene. I hope I got the right track.

Comment: So would there be a notable amount of 1,3-cyclohexadiene at low and controlled temperature and pressure

Comment: The temperature isn't the key thing here. The only requirement for a kinetically controlled reaction is that the reaction is not reversible. The last step in the Birch reduction, *protonation* of a highly basic anion, is for all intents and purposes completely irreversible.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I didn't consider the protonation step here. I got it 